# Empty unix script (.pl)

Tags: bash, unix

Here's the scenario:

I have a unix script (.pl) installed on a machine. From time to time for no apparent reason the script content is deleted.

I can not tell if it is human error, the fact is that the script itself is not deleted, only the content that disappears. How can I avoid this?

The workaround is to copy the same script from another machine.

Comment: I'd guess that the script clears some intended output file and then adds to it as it goes along, but somewhere/somehow it is called with a missing parameter or filename and it has its own name in the variable and it empties/clears itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to find a solution to a problem that hasn't been clearly understood yet. Nevertheless, here are two ideas you might consider:

- Change file's ownership / write access to prevent other users, or even yourself, from editing this script.
- Use inotify to know precisely when this file is edited and by whome, then fix the real problem instead of trying to restore this script periodicaly.